# Settled Syrian in Germany to visit UK

Tags: visas, uk

A Syrian who has a residence permit for Germany, has passed his German speaking course and will soon start to study at a German university would like to visit me.
He and another German friend, who is also his landlady, are hoping to travel together.

What do we need to do to convince Immigration he is a visitor and settled in Germany?

Comment: Are you providing accommodation or maintenance?

Answer (score 1):

He needs his residence permit or similar documentation. He needs to apply for a UK visa with all the necessary supporting documents. All other documents like a lease, utility bills in his name, etc which with confirm his ties to Germany.

https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf

Good luck.